# Custom CSS to resize elements in multiple categories

Tags: categories, css

I am using the following custom css (in a WordPress theme) to resize a certain element but only if it is in a particular category:

```
.category-69  #main  {width: 300px!important;}
.category-16  #main  {width: 300px!important;} 
.category-15 #main   {width: 300px!important;}
```

I will need these CSS rules on at least 250 different category ids, is there an easier way to group them?

Comment: how is it related to wordpress?, This is a CSS/HTML question

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you could use the [CSS begins with selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) to select all div's that begin with `category-`

```
div[class*='category-'] #main { width: 300px!important; }
```

so as you add them, it will still affect any class that begins with them.  Then, assuming you have 1 or 2 categories you don't want to have the property, you could simply override them AFTER the rule above.

```
div.category-44 #main { /*do something else*/ }
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for the feedback. I have tried the code but it doesn't work. Basically there are a couple hundred categories (possibly more) where I want to apply this and also quite a few where it won't be applied. So, I was hoping to add the resize in some sort of category list (separated with commas) rather than each on it's own line. Also, wasn't sure where to add this question but it is a wordpress theme I am working with. Thanks again - Andrew